# Xen, XAPI, and Xen Orchestra, Ubuntu 14.04 Server

Tags: 14.04, server, virtualization, xen

I'am quite new to this topic and wanted to setup an Xen Environment for testing things on a spare machine.

For this I followed this tutorial: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Xen
But as I would also like to play around with "Xen Orchestra", it seems that I need XAPI (xe).
But when I tried to install it, I discovered that the package has been removed from official repositories due to problems, and as "xcp" seems to be deprecated I question myself if the "xcp-xapi" package would be the right one to use anyway.

I also read [Ubuntu 14.04, Xen 4.4 and XAPI toolstack](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461471/ubuntu-14-04-xen-4-4-and-xapi-toolstack),
and my question is related to it.

How can I use XAPI on 14.04?
Or is there no (easy) possibility at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

I am into the same thing, I want to try the Xen Orchestra on Ubuntu, according to recent blog post on xen blog about Docker and XenServer, Xen Orchestra works with Xen and XAPI without XenServer, thus you could try to mount the iso installation image from XenServer download page and try to follow the [guide](https://wiki.xenserver.org/index.php?title=Installing_the_Xen_Cloud_Platform_(XCP)_Command_Line_Interface_(CLI)_(XE)) about installing xapi-xe package. It's rpm and I don't know how it would behave in Ubuntu, but it's worth a shot.

mount the iso, cd into it, copy xaip-xe package to your home directory

install instructions:

```
apt-get install stunnel4
alien --scripts xapi-xe-0.2-supply-correct-number-here.i686.rpm
dpkg -i ./xapi-xe_0.2-1_i386.deb
```